# Inkscape does not remember last directory

Tags: inkscape

I'm using the Inkscape snap (1.2.2-732a01da63-2022-12-09-cust) and every time I select "Save As" or "Export" the file dialog always navigates to my home directory. This is very annoying, as I expect it to remember the last directory I saved in.

Any way to fix this?

Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should be reported..

Comment: Likely an issue related to the snap packaging. Remove the version you installed and install the regular version instead. And it is good to report this issue or upvote if it is reported already.

Comment: With inkscape from apt I have the problem that it hangs as soon as I click New Document in the start-up dialog :(. I should probably get around to filing bugs for both of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

not really an OS issue but look here: press ctrl+shift+e
get to the export menu and set filename/directory

[image: export inkscape]

Comment: The thing is, I have the problem with the regular File->Save dialog. The same behavior appears if I press "Export As..."